# Sobre a nasalidade de palavras terminadas em “ã”

Tags: pronúncia, fonologia, fonemas

Um clássico truque ensinado por professores nos tempos de escola ao ensinar sobre vogais nasais é mostrar que, com o nariz fechado, ao pronunciarmos palavras com sons nasais, sentimos nele uma vibração. Se isso de fato acontece em palavras como *campo*, *ganso*, *tonto*, *alecrim* e *homem*, não me parece 100% claro que o mesmo ocorra em outras palavras com sons denominados nasais, mais especificamente daquelas terminadas em *ã*, como *hortelã*, *lã* e *fã*.

Se pronuncio a palavra *cidadã* com o nariz tampado, não sinto vibração alguma no nariz nem o som da palavra muda (comparado ao que é emitido quando não o tampo). O que sai é um som mais fechado, ou melhor, algo muito parecido com o *schwa* da língua inglesa. Exatamente o mesmo ocorre com todas as pessoas ao meu redor, no Sul do Brasil (de onde sou).

Como a lusofonia não se resume ao Sul do Brasil, decidi fazer uma pesquisa muito amadora, escutando pessoas de regiões distintas em entrevistas de televisão. Os paulistas pareceram ter a mesma pronúncia que os sulistas, enquanto pessoas de lugares como o Rio de Janeiro e vários estados do Nordeste demonstraram de fato a nasalidade que teria o *ã*, cujo som, das suas bocas, com os seus sotaques, parece soar até “meloso”. Para os cariocas, por exemplo, o som do *ã* em hortelã é bem mais alongado do que o meu. Em relação aos portugueses, o que pude perceber é que o seu som é bastante aberto, muito diferente do que se ouve do Brasil, pelo que não consigo fazer uma boa descrição de como se pronuncia na Europa.

É possível afirmar que o *ã* final de certas palavras do português nem sempre é pronunciado como um som nasal? Ou a minha impressão está equivocada, e há critérios mais amplos para definir um som nasal?

Comment: Sou carioca e pronunciamos com som nasalizado.  Pronuncio as vogais finais de cidadã, hortelã, avelã com  o mesmo som.

Comment: Vocês sentem a vibração no nariz, é isso?

Comment: Sim, eu percebo a vibração.  Se tento não ter a vibração nasal o som produzido acaba sendo igual ao do segundo "a" de cidadã..

Answer (score 3):

Fico muito feliz de encontrar seu post, pois eu, como porto-alegrense, já tinha reparado nessa mesma característica da variedade linguística falada por aqui. Obrigado por compartilhar suas perspectivas e a sua pesquisa.

No meu caso, eu percebi que pronuncio o ã de palavras como hortelã ou maçã "como se fosse" um acento circunflexo. Escrevo entre aspas porque o acento circunflexo na letra a vem sempre em uma sílaba tônica nasal, o que significa que, teoricamente, sempre é pronunciado com ar passando pela cavidade nasal, mas o que quero dizer é que pronuncio essas palavras sem nasalidade na última vogal.
De fato, sobre a pronúncia do a com acento circunflexo em "lâmina", parece-me que ocorre algo parecido, pois diz-se que é uma sílaba tônica nasal; a diferença é que posso pronunciá-la das duas maneiras (nasal ou oral) e as duas me soam naturais, embora quando eu a pronuncie nasalmente essa nasalidade não seja tão intensa como a de palavras com "ão" ou "õe", por exemplo.

Pesquisando sobre, não encontrei nada que indicasse a ocorrência dessa desnasalização, até que hoje decidi pesquisar novamente e encontrei sua publicação. Não consigo entender o porquê de tal informação não poder ser facilmente encontrada na internet, uma vez que a suposta área da característica não seria tão pequena, já que incluiria pelo menos a região metropolitana de Porto Alegre, e provavelmente o resto do estado, além da cidade de São Paulo.

Se conferimos a [seção de fonologia do artigo sobre o dialeto gaúcho na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_ga%C3%BAcho#Fonologia), podemos encontrar uma breve referência à produção de vogais nasais:

> A fonologia é bastante próxima do espanhol rioplatense, sendo algumas de suas características o ritmo silábico de fala, a vocalização do "l" em "u" no final de sílabas, e a menor importância das vogais nasais, praticamente restrita à vogal "ã" e aos ditongos "ão" e "õe".

No [artigo em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ga%C3%BAcho_dialect#Phonology) é possível encontrar algo ainda mais específico sobre o monotongo /ɐ̃/:

> In some other cities of the region, the nasal monophthong /ɐ̃/ is heightened to /ə̃/.
> [Em algumas outras cidades da região, o monotongo nasal /ɐ̃/ é elevado a /ə̃/.]

No entanto, nada indicando alguma desnasalização.

Comment: Tiago, bem-vindo ao site. Fiz umas coisitas na tua resposta. Vê se gostas. Se não gostares, clica "Edit" (canto inferior esquerdo) e faz "rollback" (volta à versão anterior) ou muda à tua vontade: é a tua resposta. Que é que eu fiz? Incluí links às tuas fontes; é útil. Pus as citações em bloco (creio que era isso o que tu querias; no texto fonte, fazias parágrafo; mas isso só resulta se deixares uma linha de intervalo). Corrigi "aumentado" para "elevado ("/ɐ̃/ é elevado a /ə̃/"; "elevar"; porque a língua se eleva fisicamente na boca, ou "reduzir", não sei porquê, são os termos técnicos).

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções, gosto delas sim. É a minha primeira resposta no site e não o conhecia muito bem.

Comment: Excelente. Tu dizes que o acento circunflexo vem sempre em vogal nasal. Mas não, não há nasalidade em *vê, lêvedo, trôpego*, etc. O ^ indica apenas timbre fechado. O *â* é que é sempre nasal "de raiz" (*c**ân**taro*) ou sofre alguma nasalação por influência de consoante nasal seguinte (*c**â**mara*). Mas isto é acidental: o *a* tónico só tem timbre fechado nessas situações (não temos palavras como *pâssaro*).

Answer (score 1):

O til é uma notação de nasalidade, senão a palavra não teria til. Hortela (sem acento) seria pronunciado como Hortéla. (Palavras terminadas em "a" e sem acento são paroxítonas).

- Hortelâ (com acento circunflexo) seria fechado e não nasalado.
- Hortelã (com til) é o correto, com som nasal.

O que pode variar é a duração e intensidade da nasalidade, de acordo com a pessoa ou região.

Algumas palavras fogem à regra quanto ao som nasal.
Por exemplo, segundo a norma técnica a palavra "muito" deve ser pronunciada com som brevemente nasal, apesar de não ter til:

- A pronúncia *mui-to* é incorreta.
- A pronúncia *muin-to* (com o som brevemente anasalado) é a correta.

Comment: Pois então, eu sei perfeitamente disso. É “hortelã”, uma oxítona em tese com som nasal. A questão é que a pronúncia que eu percebo não é nasal, mas sim só uma pronúncia fechada, como se a palavra fosse grafada com o acento circunflexo (hortelâ). Eu, a não ser forçando, não consigo ver diferença entre “hortelã” e “hortelâ”.

Comment: A norma técnica do português dita isso. Isso é "opcional" na linguagem do dia-a-dia. Já teve um professor estrangeiro? Eles costumam cometer mutos "errinhos" de gramática e fonética e talvez alguns erros imperdoáveis para um nativo, é mais ou menos a mesma coisa. E sem contar que tais sons são muito similares e não há palavra parecida para causar confusão, dificilmente um interlocutor ficaria na dúvida ao ouvir "hortelâ" ou "hortelã". Lembrando que a linguagem é uma coisa viva e existem incontáveis variações, mas relativo à norma culta (oficial), normalmente é uma academia que dita as regras.

Comment: Para você ver isso na prática teste "hortelâ" e "hortelã" em um sintetizador de voz online (https://www.readspeaker.com/pt/). Os engenheiros que desenvolvem esse tipo de aplicativo seguem a norma técnica mais a risca.